# How do I handle Ctrl+C in a Delphi console application?

Tags: delphi, console

Are there best practices and code snippets available which show how I can handle Ctrl+C in a Delphi console application?

I have found some articles which give some information about possible problems with the debugger, with exception handling, unloading of DLLs, closing of stdin, and finalization [for example this CodeGear forums thread](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=15832).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From Windows API ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016.aspx)):

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleCtrlHandler(
    PHANDLER_ROUTINE HandlerRoutine,    // address of handler function  
    BOOL Add    // handler to add or remove 
   );
```

A HandlerRoutine function is a function that a console process specifies to handle control signals received by the process. The function can have any name.

```
BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(
    DWORD dwCtrlType    //  control signal type
   );
```

---

In the Delphi the handler routine should be like:

```
function console_handler( dwCtrlType: DWORD ): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  // Avoid terminating with Ctrl+C
  if (  CTRL_C_EVENT = dwCtrlType  ) then
    result := TRUE
  else
    result := FALSE;
end;
```

Comment: Ok, this shows how I can disable Ctrl+C - I should clarify my question: how do I perform a clean application shutdown after detecting Ctrl+C?

Comment: Oh, I see. If you trap the Ctrl+C, like my example, you can set a sort of 'flag' and terminate *normally* whenever you want.

Comment: I just remembered the "break := false;" that I used to put in my Turbo Pascal programs to disable Ctrl-Break. Ah, nostalgia...

Comment: On very important thing to remember is that HandlerRoutine runs in a SEPARATE THREAD. If you don't start any other threads yourself, set the IsMultithread global variable to True so that any memory operations you perform will be safe.

Comment: Also important is the calling convention. The callback function must use the stdcall calling convention or else your program will crash mysteriously.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I forgot it. From now on it's a wiki, to further improve it.

Comment: To install this handler :   Windows.setConsoleCtrlHandler ( @console_handler, True {add } );

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little program to show you how to stop properly a background task.
Hopefully it is clearer.

Content of ThreadConsoleApplication.dpr file :

```
program ThreadConsoleApplication;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  Classes;

type
  { **
    * Classe TQueueReaderTestApplication
    * }
  TThreadConsoleApplication = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;

    constructor Create; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    class function getInstance: TThreadConsoleApplication;
  end;

function TThreadConsoleApplication_consoleCtrlHandler(dwCtrlType: DWORD): BOOL;
  stdcall; forward;

{ **
  * Classe TQueueReaderTestApplication
  * }

constructor TThreadConsoleApplication.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True { CreateSuspended } );
  Windows.setConsoleCtrlHandler(@TThreadConsoleApplication_consoleCtrlHandler,
    True { add } );
end;

var
  threadConsoleApplicationInstance: TThreadConsoleApplication = nil;

destructor TThreadConsoleApplication.Destroy;
begin
  threadConsoleApplicationInstance := nil;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TThreadConsoleApplication.Execute;
begin
  System.Writeln('[TThreadConsoleApplication.Execute] begin');
  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      System.Writeln('[TThreadConsoleApplication.Execute] running ...');
      Windows.Sleep(1000 { dwMilliseconds } );
    end;
  finally
    System.Writeln('[TThreadConsoleApplication.Execute] end');
  end;
end;

class function TThreadConsoleApplication.getInstance: TThreadConsoleApplication;
begin
  if nil = threadConsoleApplicationInstance then
  begin
    threadConsoleApplicationInstance := TThreadConsoleApplication.Create;
  end;
  Result := threadConsoleApplicationInstance;
end;

function TThreadConsoleApplication_consoleCtrlHandler(dwCtrlType: DWORD): BOOL;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Windows.CTRL_C_EVENT = dwCtrlType then
  begin
    TThreadConsoleApplication.getInstance.Terminate;
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

var
  thread: TThread;

begin
  System.Writeln('[program] begin');
  try
    thread := nil;
    try
      thread := TThreadConsoleApplication.getInstance;
      thread.Resume;
      System.Writeln('[program] press a CTRL+C to stop running');
      thread.WaitFor;
    finally
      thread.Free;
    end;
    System.Writeln('[program] end');
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      System.Writeln(System.ErrOutput, '[program] end with error');
      System.Writeln(System.ErrOutput, E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  end;
  System.Writeln('[program] press a key to quit');
  System.Readln;

end.
```