# Console Application On Termination

Tags: delphi, console-application, terminate

What is best method to free up memory when my console application terminates?

I would like to free up any related loaded DLLs and any other resources consumed by my application.

I want to free all things in memory :)

I have searched Google but could not find a way to do this.

I'm not using Units in my application it just console application

```
program MyAPP;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

/// functions 
// procedures 

begin
end.
```

Comment: "What is best method to free up memory when my console
application terminates?" actually there is a good argument that it's best to do nothing at all and let system reclaim memory

Answer (score 7):

```
begin

  try
    // Your entire program goes here.
  finally
    SomeFunction;
  end;

end.
```

Comment: this is not related on termination ? it just try something and then finally free it ?

Comment: @user1023395: I am not quite sure I understand what you wish to achieve. Perhaps you could elaborate a little?

Comment: on application exit i wanted to call some function

Comment: @user This absolutely is related to termination. If you are not prepared to tell us what your code is like and make us guess, then what sort of answer do you expect?  +1

Comment: Will SomeFunction be called if the user hits Ctrl+C?

Comment: FINALLY get called exactly after try not on when u terminate application suppose I'm calling DLL and its function in TRY and unloading dll and functions in FINALLY?

Comment: For understanding what will happen when Ctrl-C is pressed see here [forums.codegear](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=15832) and here [how-do-i-handle-ctrlc-in-a-delphi-console-applicatio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000223/how-do-i-handle-ctrlc-in-a-delphi-console-application)

Comment: @LU RD the first link triggers a security alert, but https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=15832 works

Comment: @mjn, thanks. I guess that the codegear certificate isn't updated properly anymore. I snipped the link from the SO thread.

Answer (score 0):

When your application terminates all memory allocated by it either directly or by Delphi internal allocator (TObject.Create / InitInstance) or by modules is freed by operating system.

Even memory leaks within the application are not an issue after program was terminated. You can check for memory leaks by using FastMM4 library.

Windows should also free it's objects for which you have obtained handles by initialization calls to specialized libraries like GDIPlus yet these should be freed manually after object instance became obsolete in the local scope of the code using them.

For all in-code deallocations you should use try..finally. So your program.dpr might ideally look like:

```
program YourProgram;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  MainUnit;

var
  main: TProgramMain
begin
  main := TProgramMain.Create;
  try
    main.Execute;
  finally
    main.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Will main.Free be called if the user hits Ctrl+C?

Comment: It will not be called. (reference: https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=15832 )

Answer (score 0):

You have not showed what objects you created, but whatever you did to create those objects, the reverse is how you free them, if you wish to.

Note that if your objects are simply consuming memory in the heap, you could just let Windows reclaim all memory used by your process, and the side effects of this (if there are none) might include that your tiny application shuts down faster.

Nevertheless, most conscientious developers choose to fully free every object they create. If you created an object like this:

```
  x := TMyObject.Create;
```

.. then you free it by calling Free:

```
   x.Free;
```

If the object is a component, owned by its parent, you don't need to free it.

If the object is an interfaced object (reference counted) you simply let go of your reference like this:

```
   x := nil;
```

If the type in question is a value-type (Double, Integer) then you don't have to free it.

If the type in question is automatically managed (record, string) you also don't have to free it.

If your object allocates more objects, the correct place to free them is in the destructor of that object.

These are the rules.  Just follow them, and you will have no leaks.  Your console application terminates in a manner you have not specified. Were you expecting some magic answer to your unspecified question? If it were me, I would ensure my application had an orderly shutdown, and that during normal shutdown, it frees its resources. If it terminates abnormally, then any "try..finally" blocks you have written will not be executed. I recommend you single step through your shutdown code, to see that it executes at all.

If you had posted some examples of your code, then more specific answers would have been possible.