# How can a console window program be notified when its close button is clicked?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Does the Windows API provide a way to notify a running Delphi application in a console window when the user terminates it with a click on the close button (instead of using Ctrl+C)?

Related question: [How do I handle Ctrl+C in a Delphi console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000223/how-do-i-handle-ctrlc-in-a-delphi-console-application)

Comment: Oh, come on, linked Q contains the answer! Handle CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT notification exactly in same manner as shown there.

Comment: It's all documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683242.aspx

Comment: Perhaps, @User, but people looking for the answer to *this* question wouldn't click on *that* question title. It's OK for two different questions to have the same or similar answers. It's also OK for someone to post a question that he or she already knows the answer to. It makes it easier for others to find the answer later.

Comment: @RobKennedy, perhaps? Official documentation is (was before David Heeferman added direct link) two clicks away from this question. What makes you think what people who lazy enough to perform those two clicks *will* do the same two clicks in the next copy of the same question?

Comment: They won't have to, @User. A descriptive title leads them *here*, and the answer tells them all they need. The linked question does not contain the answer to this question. It contains the answer to the linked question, and someone who happens to visit that page and click through to the documentation will learn that the function can *also* be applied with minor changes to solve this problem, but I see no reason that someone with this question would automatically assume that anything in that question is relevant here.

Comment: @RobKen, do you think what three more copies should be created for the remaining notifications? :-)

Comment: Yes, @User, if people need them. Why not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The OS notifies console programs of various events via "control signals." Call [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016.aspx) to configure [a function for the OS to call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683242.aspx) to deliver signals. The signal for a closed window is `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`.

```
function ConsoleEventProc(CtrlType: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
begin

  if (CtrlType = CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT) then
  begin
    // optionally run own code here
    // ...

  end;

  Result := True; 
end;

...

begin
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(@ConsoleEventProc, True);
  // my application code here
  // ...
end.
```