# What is equivalent of TForm1.FormCreate() and TForm1.FormCloseQuery() in console app?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to convert my application to native console app but before I can do it I need to know where to initialize code and put cleaning code when user closes program (CTRL+C). Example code

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

   InitializeCriticalSection(CriticalSection1);
   DecimalSeparator:='.';
   programdir:=ExtractFileDir(application.ExeName);

   if ParamCount>1 then
   begin
     InputFile:=ParamStr(1);
     OutputFile:=ParamStr(2);
   end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin

  if ProccesSupervisor<>nil then
  begin
    ProccesSupervisor.Terminate;
    ProccesSupervisor.WaitFor;
    ProccesSupervisor.Free;
  end;

  DeleteCriticalSection(CriticalSection1);

end;
```

Comment: They don't exist in a Console application. You need a loop with CheckSynchronize() and check for keyboard input.

Comment: Why do you need to clean up? Why kit let the system just terminate your process.

Answer (score 4):

For many purposes you can use [Initialization and Finalization](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Programs_and_Units#The_Initialization_Section) sections of main and secondary modules.

To treat Ctrl-C, you have to set [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx) routine ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000223/how-do-i-handle-ctrlc-in-a-delphi-console-application))

Note that some possibilities provided by window application are not available in console application, and to get some other possibilities, you should organize them 'by hands' (for example - OLE initialization, message cycle and so on)

Comment: Nope. Finalization doesn't run with ctrl+c